# Difference performance between service.addscope vs new instance class

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core

Way 1 new instance

```
     public class LogicPacker : ILogicPacker
     {
         private IClassDI ClassDI { get; set; }
         public LogicPacker (IClassDI ClassDI){
              this.ClassDI = ClassDI;
         }


         private ICommentervice ICommentervice { get; set; }
         public ICommentervice Commentervice
         {
             get { return ICommentervice ?? (ICommentervice = new Commentervice(ClassDI)); }
             set { ICommentervice = value; }
         }
     }
```

Way 2 AddScoped

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //IClassDI is absolutely add scope not change
        services.AddScoped<IClassDI , ClassDI>();
        ...
        services.AddScoped<ICommentservice, Commentservice>();
    }
```

Below this is my service class

```
    public class Commentservice : ICommentservice
    {

         private IClassDI ClassDI{ get; set; }
         public Commentservice(IClassDI ClassDI)
         { 
             this.ClassDI= ClassDI;
         }
    }
```

In my code i not sure about performance between use ioc AddScoped or new instance.
Way 1 i think it will be have trouble when i need to inject other to class Commentservice in future it will be make me confuse and annoying.
But Way 1 when i have more class in ILogicPacker i just inject ILogicPacker and need not to inject service anymore to other class is need to use service (if inject to much it will be new instance at constructor to much that i think)
Way 2 is use ioc add that to startup and don't be worry about number of di is need to inject to service.
If have something i think it wrong tell me and comment please.

Comment: Yes may i know some thing is best way for you can suggest me? or i need to code with design pattern good is best than interested about performance?

Comment: If you use Way 1 then you will get into problems when ILogicPacker is used for lots of different classes. It will be more confusing to understand and, more importantly, unit test. You should use Way 2 and let DI handle the object creation for you. If you need to update a constructor to add more classes then that is good because when you see yourself injecting lots of classes then that is a sign that the class is doing too much and needs to be refactored out to smaller classes.

Comment: This looks like a Prime Example for the Performance Rant: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ Tl;Dr: If there is any difference, it is to miniscule to mater and you should be your decision for/against anything on the thousand of factors besides speed.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really about performance, it's about managing lifetimes and scopes. While instantiating a class incurs some performance hit, it's usually too minuscule to even note, like micro or even nanoseconds. The reason to use DI is to scope dependencies and reuse dependencies.

Consider `DbContext`, for example. It handles things like change tracking and implements object caches, enabling things like relationship fix-up without having to issue additional queries. However, for those things to function properly, you need to use the same instance everywhere. If you create a new instance every time you use it, then the change tracking can get off, sometimes with disastrous effects, and at the very least, you lose out of all the various performance optimizations it offers. A DI container lets you share dependencies like this without having to think about it.

There's also the issue of handling object disposal, which a lot of people don't think about. If you new up a bunch of stuff in a class, you should also dispose of those things when no longer needed. This is handled via the `IDisposable` interface, which is deceptively hard to implement *correctly*. If you fail to dispose of the things you new up, you're essentially leaking memory. Sure, the GC will *eventually* clean up after you, but relying on the GC is just bad design. A DI container takes the thought out of this as well. It controls the lifetime of the objects it injects, and disposes of them when it *truly* makes sense to. Your classes are simply injected with the dependencies, so it's no longer the classes' concern as to when or if the resources are disposed. And, of course, reducing concerns is a fundamental paradigm of good design.